# Capitalization of "site" in the Data Explorer's footer

Tags: bug, data-explorer, footer, capitalization

There's a small capitalization inconsistency in the footer between the main site and the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

On SE the footer has the word *"Site"* capitalized while it's written *"site"* using small case in the Data Explorer.

[image: screenshot of footers]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Data Explorer is [open source](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/), and even though I'm not able to run it on this machine, I'm comfortable making minor textual changes. I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/120) to fix this and some old links which were still HTTP. I hope it gets merged somewhere in the next 6-8 weeks...

Comment: PR approved and merged. I have another SEDE change queued up and am planning to deploy it this week (pending some dependency changes to the servers). So barring unforeseen issues, this change will go out this week.

Comment: This change has been deployed.