# Data Explorer throws server error when attempting to query Psychology & Neuroscience

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, 500-server-error, site-name

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com) lets you write SQL queries to find questions, answers, comments, users etc across the StackExchange network, but the query interface throws an error if I try to select Psychology & Neuroscience as the target site.

[image: dropdown lets me select ...]

The problem seems to be the ampersand in the site's name; all the other sites with ampersands (Unix & Linux, Science Fiction & Fantasy, English Language & Usage, etc) have it replaced with "and" in the site dropdown.

[image: ... but I get a screenful of error messages]

URL: https://data.stackexchange.com/psychology%20&%20neuroscience/query/1677462/common-typos-lite-newest

Thanks to the friendly people on the site meta, I was given a workaround (you can replace the site name with `cogsci` in the erroneous URL) but they suggested I report the fundamental problem here instead.
Ref: [How do I run a SEDE query for this site?](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2642/how-do-i-run-a-sede-query-for-this-site?noredirect=1#comment6141_2642)

Comment: That's a bug in SEDE, causing a site name to generate 500 server error, tagged according to this now. :)

Comment: [Same bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216254/programming-puzzles-code-golf-throws-an-error-on-the-data-explorer) that was "fixed" by replacing "&" with the word "and". Sadly enough, Nick is long gone, and there's nobody to push SEDE changes, so this one is unlikely to get fixed.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I got a change merged [6-8 months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380224/295232), so there's still hope ...

Comment: Brrrrr, pending PRs from 2020 https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pulls ... but actually one was merged only a month ago.

Comment: The required change is somewhat more involved because it's not enough to replace the ampersand with "and"; https://data.stackexchange.com/psychology%20and%20neuroscience/query/1677462/common-typos-lite-newest does not work either. The site was renamed so the new name needs to be mapped to the original name somehow. I looked at the old PR but it didn't seem to directly touch these mappings.

Comment: heh that's weird. But essentially it's SEDE "fault", its base design is just bad if ampersand crash it like that. Ideally someone will go and fix it so that it can handle it without crashing, thus saving future bugs whenever SE will have another site with ampersand in its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should now be fixed. We've updated the data directly to replace `&` with `and` in the site's `Name` and `LongName` values.

Comment: Won't it be overriden in the next update, or cause other bugs as the actual site name has "&"?

Comment: The name exposed to SEDE is independent of the name of the site itself (that’s where it originally comes from, but it is not kept in sync). This is how other sites such as Unix & Linux, etc. already appear in SEDE, as noted in the question.

Comment: why not keep them in sync?

Comment: @Ooker Because they really don't change very often, if ever; Data Explorer is not even "connected" to the main sites in any active/permanent way; and, because keeping `&` would require changes to established parts of the codebase that we're not currently working on and that weren't written with the forethought that we'd later add sites with `&` in the name.